# How to get URL of apk artifact once edit is committed on Google Play Console

Tags: android, bash, apk, google-developers-console

I'm using the Google Play Developer API to upload my Android apk, assign it to the correct track and commit the edit.

That works fine.

However, as part of my workflow that I'm trying to automate, I would like to get the apk artifact URL, and post that URL on an private web server. Other team members I work with would then use the URL posted on that web server to download the apk and do some testing.

So, is there a way, using BASH scripting, to POST a command to get the apk artifact URL?

Answer (score 0):

There is beside alpha/beta testing no way for way to destitute apks with Google. I would suggest just to create a custom gradle task and upload it to your server. If you wish you could use also some other tools like hockey app. Here is just as example how you would use it with crashlitics: https://fabric.io/features/distribution

Answer (score 0):

The Play Console does not expose the URL of the artifacts you have uploaded through the API.

Use the [Alpha or Beta tracks](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB) for this kind of testing.